# What restrictions does Android put in place on activities viewed on top of a secure keyguard with FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED?

Tags: android, lockscreen, restrictions, keyguard

I'm trying to create a new lock screen and I'm aware that if I use the FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD for use with non-secured lock screens, I can present multiple functions and don't have any restrictions to intent access.

However, I've been having a very difficult time identifying what limitations are implemented if the user had a secure (password, pin, pattern, etc) keyguard active and I use the FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED.

For example, if my activity is visible over the keyguard and the user wanted to change the background of the activity to a picture they took, they cannot access the gallery to select the photo if the phone is locked.

I couldn't find anything in the Android SDK documentation or on here (or anywhere for that matter) that could answer what other functions are disabled. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!